# Apache/PHP7.3 running in Docker randomly drops connection with empty response

Tags: apache, docker, php-7.3

I have found several similar questions:

- [APACHE, PHP Server return randomly empty response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325120/apache-php-server-return-randomly-empty-response)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/66662/apache-gives-empty-reply
- and others

However these does not seem to help to find the cause. I can replicate the behaviour when reloading a specific page ~20 times.

1. Running current apache2 (= 2.4.38-3+deb10u4). I tried to disable opcache, remove `MaxRequestsPerChild` with no effect.
2. Apache log does not show any error. The request is not even logged.
3. The `USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0` seem to have no effect and the problem persists.
4. I tried to install `mod_forensic` which shows that the request came in. No error or finished request is then logged.
5. The container is running in Kubernetes and I cannot replicate the issue locally running directly with Docker machine, that is why I think this might be caused by some memory setting. However I couldn't find what might be causing this as there is no single error message.

Can you think of any reason why this might be happening?

**Edit1:**

I tried to set log level to trace:

https://gist.github.com/knyttl/861e8a0fe5651408df37cd5c3874946b

The request is handled and then you can see:

```
[Tue Oct 20 08:37:55.825454 2020] [core:trace4] [pid 1] mpm_common.c(536): mpm child 388 (gen 2/slot 4) exited
```

With no error and no response.

**Edit2:**

I updated to php7.4 and the issue persists.

Comment: what's the setup? prefork mpm + php apache module? you could try troubleshooting by starting apache with max one worker, attaching to it with `gdb`, put breakpoint on exit and then walk back from there (you may need to compile apache and php yourself to be able to step through the sources). If you have a segfault (which you could find in the kernel log), being attached would also allow you to look that without relying on having a coredump being generated. Consider also moving to php-fpm

Comment: Unfortunately I think it might be out of my capacities to debug with `gdb` :/

I will try the php-fpm – is the behaviour very different? Are you aware of issues which were sorted with such migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it:

The process is silently killed by OOM killer of the host machine:

```
[4019392.626796] Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 4178127 (apache2) score 1137 or sacrifice child
[4019392.636520] Killed process 4178127 (apache2) total-vm:143960kB, anon-rss:22856kB, file-rss:10472kB, shmem-rss:28228kB
```

This is never logged within the container so it was hard to find.

Comment: Make sure you're not using `USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0`. That flag is just for testing. The interpreter will leak memory if you do.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use Jorge's answers ?

> Finally solved by adding to /etc/apache2/envvars:
>
> export USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0

https://serverfault.com/a/66759

Comment: Did you read my question? I tried this – see point 3.